# Adding <b> tag without creating linebreak in echo?

Tags: php, html

Am new to php (been at it for a couple days) but have been working in languages like c++ and python for years. I'm currently making a basic global chat system where inputted chats are sent to a mysql database via AJAX/php. Chats are updated every 5 seconds using a similar method into an assigned div.

in the GetChat.php I filter the text before echoing it, and am trying to implement something akin to a bbcode system. However, when I use the `<b>` tag or `<span>` tag, it breaks and screws up the order of the text. Could I get some insight on how to do this part correctly?

My code for GetChat.php:

```html
<html><body>
<?php
    require_once 'dbconnection.php';
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    $chatarray = array();

    $qry = ('SELECT ChatText FROM Chat');
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)   // checking if there is any row in the resultset
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))  // Iterate for each rows
        {
            $chatarray[] = $row['ChatText'];
        }
    }

    foreach ($chatarray as $chat)
        {
        $bbcode = array("[b]", "[/b]", "[red]", "[blue]", "[/color]");
        $htmlcode = array("<b>", "</b>", "<span style='color:red'>", "<span style='color:blue'>","</span>");
        $newmessage = str_replace($bbcode, $htmlcode, $chat);

        // Convert newlines to HTML line breaks
        $newmessage = nl2br($newmessage);

        // Word wrap if necessary
        $newmessage = wordwrap($newmessage, 34, "\n", true);

        echo $newmessage . "</br></br>";
        }
?>
</body></html>
```

Output with tags:

[image]

Output without tags:

[image]

Edit:

This is how it looks in the database:

[image]

Comment: Could you check the outputted HTML code? The browser is messing the DOM up, I guess.

Comment: First of all, please present a _proper_ [mre], when you ask this kind of question. We don't know what your _exact_ input data is here - and if I try with `[b]Admin:[/b] Global Chat Test 1`, I can't reproduce your problem: https://3v4l.org/ARVlV Are you sure it is not perhaps the _formatting_, that is to blame - and that `b` elements aren't set to `display: block` via your stylesheet or something?

Comment: Second: `$newmessage = wordwrap($newmessage, 34, "\n", true);` - you can't use that on content, that will contain HTML tags - it will "rip" them apart, if they happened to be in a position where this will insert a "wrap". You're gonna end up with situations like `<span style='c[line break character here]olor:red'>` or other nonsense sooner or later, and there is of course no way the browser will render that the way you actually intended.

Comment: @csabinho sure! Here it is when I use inspection on the page in chrome. Not sure if there's a better method you prefer but please let me know! (also I apologize if there's a better way to show a pic, I couldn't find one in comments)  https://imgur.com/a/YLLuqfM

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. The input is literally just the text "[b]Admin:[/b] Test 1". Then as you see in the code above, I replace the [b] tags with <b> tags. That's really it. Formatting may be part of the issue, here's my div css: https://imgur.com/a/UMoQP9w I don't have any css for the b element though.

Regarding your second comment: I had considered if the word wrap was the issue as well, but even when removing that part entirely, the issue still remains the same. That's good information to know though, thank you!

Comment: @LiterallyMom: Instead of screenshots in comments, please update the question to include a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) of the relevant HTML/CSS which demonstrates the problem.  Having said that... In the (picture of) CSS you're showing you have `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column-reverse;`.  The styling is explicitly indicating that elements should be shown in a column.  Which is why elements are shown in a column.  It sounds like you may want to re-think your HTML structure and/or CSS styling.

Comment: @LiterallyMom The inspection just gives you the "made up" DOM. It's not the real source code. Try pressing Ctrl+U for the real source code.

Comment: _"here's my div css"_ - it has `display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse`, so that will make each child element a "row" of its own. Wrap your whole message that you output, into an additional `div` to avoid that.

Comment: @David Sorry, I've updated my post to include the full code for the page. This page is refreshed every few seconds via ajax on the main page, and the info inserted into the div on the main page. I can also show you this portion of code on the main page if you like. I just didn't want to overload the question with too much.

Comment: @LiterallyMom: A [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) of *PHP code* is kind of pointless, PHP doesn't run in the browser.  The updated question does not contain the relevant HTML and CSS which appears to be causing the issue.  No "line breaks" are being inserted.  The resulting display is exactly what the CSS defines it to be.  You'll probably want to style it differently, because currently your styling indicates that these elements *should* be rendered in a column, which they are.

Comment: @David oh it looks like you nailed it, the issue was the div css. How silly of me. Thank you so much for your help, I'll be sure to mark the answer. It's always the simple things that cause the most problems in coding, haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the order of execution, php works in cascade

```
foreach ($chatarray as $chat) {
  // Replace BBCode-like tags with HTML
  $bbcode = array("[b]", "[/b]", "[red]", "[blue]", "[/color]");
  $htmlcode = array("<b>", "</b>", "<span style='color:red'>", "<span style='color:blue'>","</span>");
  $newmessage = str_replace($bbcode, $htmlcode, $chat);

  // Convert newlines to HTML line breaks
  $newmessage = nl2br($newmessage);

  // Word wrap if necessary
  $newmessage = wordwrap($newmessage, 34, "\n", true);

  echo $newmessage . "</br></br>";
}
```

Now in the code you first replace the BBCode tags with HTML tags

If this doesn't work, the error could also be in the text you enter. If so, could you add the text how and where you insert it?